# I have a php application that will work when i run it from a webpage but not when i cron the standalone php file

Tags: php, cron

my problem is pretty crazy. Because, i have a FULLY WORKING PHP script that runs when i execute the webpage with this code..

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello</P>
<?php
$file1 = file_get_contents("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph/440.json");
$file2 = file_get_contents("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph            /434.json");
$file3 = file_get_contents("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph/10294.json");
$file4 = file_get_contents("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph/2621.json");
$file5 = file_get_contents("../json/440.json");
$file6 = file_get_contents("../json/434.json");
$file7 = file_get_contents("../json/10294.json");
$file8 = file_get_contents("../json/2621.json");
if(($file1 != $file5)or($file2 != $file6)or($file3 != $file7)or($file4 != $file8))
{








$my_t=getdate(date("U"));
$hour = $my_t[hours];
$setTime = 12;
$ending = " # ";
if($hour > $setTime){
$hour-=$setTime;
$ending = "PM";
}else{
$ending = "AM";
}

print($file);
print("$my_t[weekday], $my_t[month] $my_t[mday], $my_t[year]   $hour:$my_t[minutes] $ending");
 $to = "php.tester@mailinator.com";
 $subject = "Ge Has Updated";
 $body = "$my_t[weekday], $my_t[month] $my_t[mday], $my_t[year]     \n$hour:$my_t[minutes] $ending";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent to ".$to." !</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }

copy("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph/440.json","../json/440.json");
copy("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph/434.json","../json/434.json");
copy("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph/10294.json","../json/10294.json");
copy("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph/2621.json","../json/2621.json");

 } 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

BUT when i just strip out the content in the `<?php.... ?>` tags... but i also copy the php tags as well. and save as a standalone php script that i use a Cron to run every five minutes. it willnot work. Any help?

ps. i have tried manually editing my local .json files just to make sure that it isnt working.

EDIT: i copied starting with `<?php` and ending with `?>` everything. that includes the tags.

Comment: Can you run the script from the command line? Also note that the webserver and cron run as different users and you may not have permissions to copy the files.

Comment: my money on a user permission issue

Comment: Did you really _strip out the content in the `<?php... ?>` tags_? How do you expect anything to happen then? Post the exact script that you're trying to execute as a cronjob.

Comment: @lanzz i mean by that that i copy it into a file and save as .php... yes that includes the `<?php... ?>` also.

Comment: @Dagon if it IS a user permission issue. is there somewhere else that will host my php file with cron for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the script executable.  I would also probably change the relative path in the script itself to an absolute path.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work

Comment: I think the relative paths are what are getting with me. but how would i go about the copy() with an absolute path then? considering the only thing i know to do is to put the url of the .json files in there. but im assuming copy() wont write to a url because it wont have access. how do i get around this?

Comment: I don't think copy is the way to go here.  Given that this is run on the command line you can safely use shell_exec and wget to grab this file and dump it on the absolute path that you need.  If you don't want to use shell exec you can use curl in php to do the same thing ( assuming you have the curl extension installed ).  Here is an example of using wget and curl from the command line http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/wget-curl/

Answer (score 0):

A PHP script will not run without the `<?php....?>` tags.

Comment: i do have them pardon my way of wording the question.

Comment: ohk, what's the command you use for running the script? any errors?

Comment: i used the php -f command to run it. or at least the cron hosting thing does.